# parent vs closest

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Why does this work:

```
$('.button_30').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.portlet').find('.portlet_content').text("foo");
});​
```

any why does this not work:

```
$('.button_30').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('.portlet').find('.portlet_content').text("foo");
});​
```

where the html looks something like this:

```
<div class="portlet portlet_30">

    <div class="portlet_header portlet_header_30">
        header content here
    </div>

    <div class="portlet_sub_header portlet_sub_header_30">
        <input type="text" class="textbox_30" />
    </div>

    <div class="portlet_content portlet_content_30">
        results go here
    </div>

    <div class="portlet_footer portlet_footer_30">
        <input type="button" class="button_30" />
    </div>

</div>

<div class="portlet portlet_30">

    <div class="portlet_header portlet_header_30">
        header content here
    </div>

    <div class="portlet_sub_header portlet_sub_header_30">
        <input type="text" class="textbox_30 />
    </div>

    <div class="portlet_content portlet_content_30">
        results go here
    </div>

    <div class="portlet_footer portlet_footer_30">
        <input type="button" class="button_30" />
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Because `.portlet` is not the parent of `.button_30`, `.portlet_footer` is the parent.

Comment: It is compared with parents here: https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Because [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent) will return the parent (immediate ancestor) **only** if it matches the selector specified.

However, [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) will search *all* ancestors and return the **first** one that matches the selector.

As the parent of `button_30` is a `div`, whose parent is the `div` with the class of `portlet`, the `parent()` function is not matching it and returning an empty set, where-as `closest()` **is** matching it.

---

To complete the set of similar methods here you have [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents), which is like `closest()` but *doesnt* stop at the first matched element; it returns all ancestors which match the selector.

Answer (score 36):

- [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) only looks at the immediate ancestor.
- [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) looks at all ancestors, as well as the originating element, and returns the first match.
- [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) looks at all ancestors, and returns all matches.

Comment: Interesting performance comparison between closest and parents here: http://jsperf.com/jquery-parents-vs-closest/45

Answer (score 1):

`parent()` only looks one level up, you can try `parents()` to search all way up

```
$('.button_30').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.portlet').find('.portlet_content').text("foo");
});​
```

you can see the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

Answer (score 1):

The `closest`*<sup>[[API Ref]](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)</sup>* method traverses up the ancestor tree as far as it needs to go to find a selector match.

The `parent`*<sup>[[API Ref]](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)</sup>* method only looks at the direct parent.

Answer (score 1):

The `parent` method checks only one level up the chain of elements, while `closest` will keep checking the list of parents up until a match is found (or html tag has been reached).
The equivalent is:

```
$('.button_30').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.portlet:eq(0)').find('.portlet_content').text("foo");
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the only elements which match `.portlet` are *grandparents*, not parents of the elements on which the event is bound

Answer (score 0):

Because in the second selector you're looking for the Parent and this function move's into the  `DOM` to the node father but only `one level` which contains the class `portlet_footer portlet_footer_30` not the classes that you're passing to the selector `.portlet` to work with `parent` you should move two levels in other words.

`each time that you're using parent you move one node up`